# How to debug '.../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/' java files?

Tags: react-native

I can log at any line by using `android.util.Log.v(String, String)` method in a native `java` module when developing `react-native` application.
However I cannot get console output from the files that are placed on the folder of `.../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/`

I wonder that can I debug [NativeViewHierarchyOptimizer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/NativeViewHierarchyOptimizer.java) and [UIViewOperationQueue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/UIViewOperationQueue.java) classes in react-native?

In fact, I've been trying to debug for [this issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/1870).

Comment: Were you able to log to console from java files? I am trying to do same. I am doing `Log.v("ReactNative", "testing")` which shows up in `react-native log-android` but it doesn't show in Chrome Debug Tools console.

Comment: I use logcat to track logs. To run logcat 'adb shell logcat' command might be run. "ReactNative" tag can be filter by using logcat parameters: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html

Comment: Thanks efkan, so no way to log to chrome dev tools from java huh? :(

Comment: If you are a newcomer to React-Native, I recommend you to using Android-Studio for developing an Android app.

Comment: Thanks efkan very much, why do you recommend that? If it is really worth it I'll make the effort to get another computer to use Android Studio. It runs super slow on my current computer. :(

Comment: Because React-Native cannot give you a full control at native side and you may need to use Java/Kotlin sometimes. It is not a must, but if you have a chance, I recommend it.

Comment: Thanks efkan, but I needed to target iOS as well. I really appreicate your input. I've been having a great time with RN, and just out of my greed I want to make some components truly native (its already native in RN, i just want to make it even more native! haha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is building `react-native` from source as directed the following: 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/wiki/Building-from-source